# JVM Constant Pool Entries

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode

Looking at the output of running `javap` on some classes, I have come across the following oddity:

The Constant Pool of some classes contains entries such as

```
#33 = Utf8               Code
#34 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
#35 = Utf8               StackMapTable
#36 = Utf8               MethodParameters
```

Why do these constants appear in the constant pool?

Comment: Are these Constants used anywhere? hint, hint?

Comment: They are the names of various attributes such as the `LocalVariableTable`, but I don't understand why these have to be UTF-8 Strings instead of simple numerical IDs.

Comment: Do you mean like `34` ?  Using named fields makes the format easier to extend and comprehend.

Comment: You've already answered the question yourself. These are the names of class attributes in correspondence with [JVMS §4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7). In addition to predefined attributes there can be custom attributes and also new attributes may appear in future, so textual names seem to suit better.

Comment: Extension is the key, as explained in JVMS 4.7.1: `Two attributes that are intended to be distinct, but that happen to use the same attribute name and are of the same length, will conflict on implementations that recognize either attribute. Attributes defined other than in this specification must have names chosen according to the package naming convention described in The Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition (JLS §6.1).` You couldn't do this with numerical values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following constants

```
#33 = Utf8               Code
#34 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
#35 = Utf8               StackMapTable
#36 = Utf8               MethodParameters
```

are name of [attributes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7).

> For all attributes, the attribute_name_index must be a valid unsigned 16-bit index into the constant pool of the class. **The constant_pool entry at attribute_name_index must be a CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure (§4.4.7) representing the name of the attribute.**

The attributes you mention have the following functions:

- A `Code` attribute contains the Java Virtual Machine instructions and auxiliary information for a method, including an instance initialization method or a class or interface initialization method.
- The `LocalVariableTable` attribute [...] may be used by debuggers to determine the value of a given local variable during the execution of a method.
- A `StackMapTable` attribute is used during the process of verification by type checking
- A `MethodParameters` attribute records information about the formal parameters of a method, such as their names.